# How to solve circular reference detected

Tags: python, json, type-conversion, toml

I need to convert json into toml format.

When I run the following code, it returns with an error.

```
import toml

toml_config = toml.dumps(data)
```

where `data` is:

```json
{"general":{"log_level":{"value":"4","editable":"true","description":"debug=5, info=4, warning=3, error=2, fatal=1, panic=0"},"log_to_syslog":{"value":"false","editable":"true","description":"When set to true, log messages are being written to syslog."}},"postgresql":{"dsn":"true","postgres://localhost/chirpstack_ns?sslmode\n\n# Automatically apply database migrations.\n#\n# It is possible to apply the database-migrations by hand\n# (see https://github.com/brocaar/chirpstack-network-server/tree/master/migrations)\n# or let ChirpStack Application Server migrate to the latest state automatically, by using\n# this setting. Make sure that you always make a backup when upgrading ChirpStack\n# Application Server and / or applying migrations.\nautomigratemax_open_connections":0,"max_idle_connections":2},"redis":{"servers":["localhost:6379"],"password":"","database":0,"cluster":"false","master_name":"","pool_size":0},"network_server":{"net_id":"000000","deduplication_delay":"200ms","device_session_ttl":"744h0m0s","get_downlink_data_delay":{"value":"100ms","editable":"true"},"band":{"name":"EU868","uplink_dwell_time_400ms":"false","downlink_dwell_time_400ms":"false","uplink_max_eirp":-1,"repeater_compatible":"false"},"network_settings":{"installation_margin":10,"rx_window":0,"rx1_delay":1,"rx1_dr_offset":0,"rx2_dr":-1,"rx2_frequency":-1,"rx2_prefer_on_rx1_dr_lt":0,"rx2_prefer_on_link_budget":"false","gateway_prefer_min_margin":10,"downlink_tx_power":-1,"disable_mac_commands":"false","disable_adr":"false","max_mac_command_error_count":3,"enabled_uplink_channels":[],"class_b":{"ping_slot_dr":0,"ping_slot_frequency":0},"rejoin_request":{"enabled":"false","max_count_n":0,"max_time_n":0}},"scheduler":{"scheduler_interval":"1s","class_c":{"downlink_lock_duration":"2s","multicast_gateway_delay":"2s"}},"api":{"bind":"0.0.0.0:8000","ca_cert":"","tls_cert":"","tls_key":""},"gateway":{"ca_cert":"","ca_key":"","client_cert_lifetime":"8760h0m0s","backend":{"type":"mqtt","multi_downlink_feature":"hybrid","mqtt":{"event_topic":"gateway/+/event/+","command_topic_template":"gateway/{{ .GatewayID }}/command/{{ .CommandType }}","server":"tcp://localhost:1883","username":"","password":"","max_reconnect_interval":"1m0s","qos":0,"clean_session":"true","client_id":"","ca_cert":"","tls_cert":"","tls_key":""},"amqp":{"url":"amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672","event_queue_name":"gateway-events","event_routing_key":"gateway.*.event.*","command_routing_key_template":"gateway.{{ .GatewayID }}.command.{{ .CommandType }}"},"gcp_pub_sub":{"credentials_file":"","project_id":"","uplink_topic_name":"","downlink_topic_name":"","uplink_retention_duration":"24h0m0s"},"azure_iot_hub":{"events_connection_string":{"value":"","editable":"true","description":"This connection string must point to the Service Bus Queue to which the IoT Hub is forwarding the (uplink) gateway events."},"commands_connection_string":{"value":"","editable":"true","description":"This connection string must point to the IoT Hub and is used by ChirpStack Network Server for sending commands to the gateways."}}}}},"monitoring":{"bind":"","prometheus_endpoint":"false","prometheus_api_timing_histogram":"false","healthcheck_endpoint":"false"},"join_server":{"resolve_join_eui":"false","resolve_domain_suffix":".joineuis.lora-alliance.org","default":{"server":"http://localhost:8003","ca_cert":"","tls_cert":"","tls_key":""}},"network_controller":{"server":"","ca_cert":"","tls_cert":"","tls_key":""}}
```

The error I get while running above code is:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    toml_string = toml.dumps(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/toml/encoder.py", line 67, in dumps
    raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
ValueError: Circular reference detected
```

After digging in, I found that after deleting a key-value pair, the code works fine. The key-value pair is:

```
"type": "mqtt"
```

The location of this key-value pair is `data["network_server"]["gateway"]["backend"]`.

I am not able to understand this situation.
I tried to change the key-value pair string but still the same problem. Only removing this key-value pair solves the problem. But I need this pair.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem, because I planned to switch from json config to toml config too. I have installed `toml` version 0.10.1.

There is a small problem in the data (# comments after the `"postgresql"` key), but that section can be deleted entirely.

I could minimize the example to:

```
data = { 
        "network_server":{
                "downlink_data_delay":{},
                "gateway":{"key3":{"key4":{}}
                }   
        }   
}

import toml
print(toml.dumps(data)) # ValueError: Circular reference detected
```

But the weird thing is the error goes away when you keep the structure, but slightly rename the keys!!

Just delete the first 'n' from the `"network_server"` and you'll get na output!

That must be a bug. Very sad.

---

Update: After looking at the source, the bug is quite obvious.

```
retval = ""
if encoder is None:
    encoder = TomlEncoder(o.__class__)
addtoretval, sections = encoder.dump_sections(o, "")
retval += addtoretval
outer_objs = [id(o)]
while sections:
    section_ids = [id(section) for section in sections]
    for outer_obj in outer_objs:
        if outer_obj in section_ids:
            raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
    outer_objs += section_ids
    newsections = encoder.get_empty_table()
    for section in sections:
        addtoretval, addtosections = encoder.dump_sections(
            sections[section], section)

        if addtoretval or (not addtoretval and not addtosections):
            if retval and retval[-2:] != "\n\n":
                retval += "\n"
            retval += "[" + section + "]\n"
            if addtoretval:
                retval += addtoretval
        for s in addtosections:
            newsections[section + "." + s] = addtosections[s]
    sections = newsections
return retval
```

Or isn't it? OK, it tracks the `id`s of sections, but the sections are not preserved between loop iterations. When `id`s get reused, the program is confused.

Quick & dirty fix: patch the `toml/encoder.py` file, in the `dumps` function:

1. add `allsections=[]` before the while loop
2. add one line here:

   ```
        allsections += sections   # <---
        sections = newsections
    return retval
   ```

The purpose is to prevent the garbage collection of unused sections, in order to keep their `id`s in use.

Feel free to report the issue to the author at github.